# Does the rendering process of angular occur asynchronously?

Tags: angular, frontend

Angular needs to control the rendering order of certain components.

a
b
c

The page is made up of components,
All three components dynamically retrieve data via API calls
Draw on the screen.
All three components do not have a fixed length, which causes a lot of layout movements.

I'm trying to solve the layout movement problem without changing the design.

In my opinion, after the rendering of element a is completed
You want to render b,c elements by generating an event.

But when I tried this method, I found some phenomena that were different from what I expected
I'm curious about this.

1. If there is an initial value, does it happen after rendering to the initial value unconditionally?

Some values are given an initial value ([]), and ngOnInit is updating the initial value after calling api, but if the data is empty, the screen to be displayed is always rendered initially, and then the screen is updated again to match the data, resulting in layout changes.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x53bhw?file=src%2Fmain.ts

2. Adjusting rendering with ngIf, etc., exposes the moment the rendering changes to the user. The same is true if you try to render the rest after rendering a particular component (A) in ngAfterViewInit. You have to use setTimeout and hidden to hide the layout change process, but I'm curious about the cause of this phenomenon and other solutions.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjdxzn?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Each link provides a simple example of the methods I've tried. Please give me a lot of advice.

Comment: Maybe [this part of the Angular documentation with a live example](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-example-set) could be useful for you?

Comment: hard to tell what you are asking, but all formatting can be controlled by css. possibly setting min-height and min-width would get you the desired result?